# The "How to Format" div on the "Ask a Question" page overlaps the footer section

Tags: bug, status-declined, design

On the "Ask a Question" or "Update Question" page, the right div which is used to provide information about "How to Format" overlaps the content of the footer section, which hides the relevant links.

[image]

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136849/right-hand-sidebar-covers-the-footer-on-the-ask-question-page-and-markdown-hel